# How to iterate through array of object in order to push data in Mongodb nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I'm working on a blog app, and I'm coding an online editor right now, nothing fancy.

Before I start to explain my problem consider this schema which I'm using :

```
 var blogSchema = restful.model('blog-schema', mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   preview: String,
   content: [{tag: String, body: String}],
   comments: [{ body: String, date: Date}],
   createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
 }
```

On my client side, I'm using `react` to POST data which looks like this :

```
 [{"type":"h2","body":"azeaeazeae"},{"type":"p","body":"azeaeazeae"}]
```

Then within `express()` I do this :

```
 blogSchema.update(
  {title: "please work AGAIN"},
  {
     $pushAll: {
      content: test
     }
 },
 function(err, stat, docs) {
  console.log(stat);
 }
)
```

Then with POSTMAN I check if the data is well stored and I got this :

```
"content": [    
{
  "tag": "[object Object],[object Object]",
  "_id": "57b2eced869e03821d446c38"
}
```

My question, how in my server can I iterate through this array of object and then push every single item to its respective place : `tag` and `body`.

Answer (score 1):

I did find it :

here is the code :

```
app.post('/admin', function(req, res) {
   var test = req.body;

   test.map(function(test, i) {
   blogSchema.update(
   {title: "please work AGAIN"},
    {
      $push: {
        content: {
          test: test.type,
          body: test.body
        }
      }
    },
    function(err,stat,dude){
      console.log(stat);
    })
})
```

I simple mapped the req.body and then perform a $push within mongo... I'm sorry to have posted this question. So happy though !

Comment: One more question, why mongodb creates an _id for each element pushed ? 

{
      "test": "h2",
      "body": "Some body text",
      "_id": "57b2f1260397195a1f49ac64"
 }

Comment: [This link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#id-field) may give you the answer for the question in the comment.